# Flutter error: Task :app:processDebugMainManifest FAILED

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-manifest

**The error:**

```
C:\Users\DELL\OneDrive\Bureaublad\taxi_app\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:9:9-42 Error:
    Attribute application@name at AndroidManifest.xml:9:9-42 requires a placeholder substitution but no value for <applicationName> is provided.
C:\Users\DELL\OneDrive\Bureaublad\taxi_app\android\app\src\debug\AndroidManifest.xml Error:
        Validation failed, exiting
```

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.praveeshramroop.athena">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>

<application
    android:name="${applicationName}"
    android:label="athena"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="NEVER EXPOSE THIS"/>

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
       
        
        
        
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
<meta-data
android:name="flutterEmbedding"
android:value="2" />
```

This is the error, I'm getting and no idea how to solve it. There seems to be almost no post about this particular problem. Does anyone have a solution? If any further information required, do let me know.

Comment: can you remove android:name="${applicationName}" and try again running the app.

Comment: Very Important...you have exposed your Google maps API key in the post above, I deleted it but someone may already have it. Create a new one immediately. See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/start and read about securing API keys.